# Does MySQL bin log append to dump file?

Tags: mysql

I want to know whether MySql bin log appends the new transactions to the dump file or it deletes the dump file and makes a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go-through these links, i think it will be useful,

1) http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_delete-master-logs

2) http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-log.html